# running multiline shell script in docker build RUN command is not working

Tags: bash, docker, shell, dockerfile

I'm working on a building a docker image. It basically uses the `eclipse-temurin`.

The dockerfile does download some certs online and import into java based on if the java version is 8 or not.

Below is the Dockerfile

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:8

RUN curl -ksS https://myorg1.com/certs/root > Org1_CA.pem && \
    curl -ksS https://myorg2.com/certs/root > Org2_CA.pem && \
    openssl x509 -in Org1_CA.pem -inform PEM -out Org1_CA.crt && \
    openssl x509 -in Org2_CA.pem -inform PEM -out Org2_CA.crt && \
    cp Org1_CA.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/Org1_CA.crt && \
    cp Org2_CA.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/Org2_CA.crt && \
    update-ca-certificates

ARG BASE_TAG

RUN echo "BASE TAG is " ${BASE_TAG}

RUN set -eux; \
    if [ "$BASE_TAG" = "temurin-8-jammy" ] \
    then \
        mkdir -p "$JAVA_HOME""$JRE_PREFIX"/lib/security && \
        keytool -import -alias Org1Cert -keystore "$JAVA_HOME""$JRE_PREFIX"/lib/security/cacerts -file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/Org1_CA.crt -storepass changeit -noprompt && \
        keytool -import -alias Org2Cert -keystore "$JAVA_HOME""$JRE_PREFIX"/lib/security/cacerts -file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/Org2_CA.crt -storepass changeit -noprompt \
    else \
        mkdir -p "$JAVA_HOME"/conf/security && \
        keytool -importcert -alias Org1Cert -keystore "$JAVA_HOME"/conf/security/cacerts -file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/Org1_CA.crt -storetype PKCS12 -storepass changeit -noprompt  && \
        keytool -importcert -alias Org2Cert -keystore "$JAVA_HOME"/conf/security/cacerts -file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/Org2_CA.crt -storetype PKCS12 -storepass changeit -noprompt \
    fi

 RUN echo "DONE"
```

The docker build command that I'm using is -

`docker build . -t j8 --build-arg BASE_IMAGE=temurin-8-jammy --build-arg JRE_PREFIX=/jre`

But I'm getting error

> ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c did not complete successfully: exit code: 2"

When I run individual commands it is working fine but when I make it into single RUN command with if else it is giving error.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Why did you tag this _bash_? I don't see where bash would be involved. The error message doesn't come from bash either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has to be a `;` before `then`, `else`, and `fi`.

```
if something; then this; else that; fi
```

Like this:

```
RUN set -eux; \
    if [ "$BASE_TAG" = "temurin-8-jammy" ] ; \
    then \
        mkdir -p "$JAVA_HOME""$JRE_PREFIX"/lib/security && \
        keytool -import -alias Org1Cert -keystore "$JAVA_HOME""$JRE_PREFIX"/lib/security/cacerts -file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/Org1_CA.crt -storepass changeit -noprompt && \
        keytool -import -alias Org2Cert -keystore "$JAVA_HOME""$JRE_PREFIX"/lib/security/cacerts -file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/Org2_CA.crt -storepass changeit -noprompt; \
    else \
        mkdir -p "$JAVA_HOME"/conf/security && \
        keytool -importcert -alias Org1Cert -keystore "$JAVA_HOME"/conf/security/cacerts -file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/Org1_CA.crt -storetype PKCS12 -storepass changeit -noprompt  && \
        keytool -importcert -alias Org2Cert -keystore "$JAVA_HOME"/conf/security/cacerts -file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/Org2_CA.crt -storetype PKCS12 -storepass changeit -noprompt; \
    fi
```

Comment: I'm still getting same error after applying your suggestion :(

Comment: `if [ "$BASE_TAG" = "temurin-8-jammy" ] \
    then \` - right